# How to include multiple resources in a tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

How can we use tags so that when a User clicks on a tag it takes him to a new page that lists out ALL the posts with that tag in it (in other words not just from one resource but includes ALL the resources)?

I played around with creating a tags scaffold, which creates a tags index, but I started getting error after error and so I'm not sure if this is the best route ;)

**routes.rb**

```html
  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'tags#index'

  resources :habits

  resources :goals

  resources :valuations

  resources :quantifieds
  
  resources :results
```

If the only route to solving this problem is through creating a tags_controller can you offer me some advice on what I can do to make it work? Or should I work with the application controller and use partials like I did with creating a sidebar?

I followed along this episode to start: http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging

**Thank you so much for your time!**

Comment: If you are showing a particular tag, that should probably go to the `show` action on the tags controller. What does your current code look like in the `index` action?

Comment: How have you set up `tag`? is there any association with a `post` model? Are you using a particular gem?

Comment: I mimicked `get 'tags/:tag', to: 'articles#index', as: :tag` from the Railscasts Tagging episode @evanbikes.  My index action right now was just copying and pasting the valuations index action to see if it would work. I imagine that if I go the tags_controller way I'd similarly add all the resources to the index action:   def index
    if params[:tag]
      @valuations = Valuation.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @valuations = Valuation.order('RANDOM()')
    end
  end

Comment: I am using the acts-as-taggable-on gem @patrick as suggested by a Railscasts episode. There is no `post` model. I setup the tag as followed by the before mentioned episode.